# Trying to code bi-Directional Fibonacci Sequence i.e. even negative numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, fibonacci

With suggestions, trail and errors; i have iterated the code. However, i still have query:

Current Result : [1, -1, 2, -3, 5, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765]

Expected & Accurate Result: [5, -3, 2, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765]

- value has correct sequence. each value corresponds to the range value.

However, - value are reversed. (-1) position has 5 & (-5) position has 1. How do i solve it?

Also, if i try bi_fibonacci(5,10):

Ans: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5] - it consider len of the range. irrespective of values.

I would like it to show: [8, 13, 21, 34, 55] - The actual answer.

How do i solve it?

Thanks in advance.

```
def bi_fibonacci(num1, num2):
    a = 1
    b = -1
    for item in range(num1, num2+1):
        if item < 0:
            yield a
            temp = a
            a = b
            b = temp - b

    a = 0
    b = 1
    for item in range(num1,num2+1):
        if item > -1:
            yield a
            temp = a
            a = b
            b = temp + b

fibo_seq = [x for x in bi_fibonacci(-8,8)]
print(fibo_seq)
print(len(fibo_seq))
```

Comment: Lookup-Dict from -10 to 10 would be viable.

Comment: sorry, i did not understood what you meant ? Eventually, i want to make it work from -nth to nth range.

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe you need a stack for the negative fibonacci sequence.  Either an explicit stack (e.g. a `list`) or an implicit one (i.e. recursion.)  Second, you need to do careful bookkeeping on this problem.  Consider these three cases:

```
sequence = bi_fibonacci(-10, -5)
sequence = bi_fibonacci(-10, 10)
sequence = bi_fibonacci(5, 10)
```

You want to handle all three correctly but without making any of them a special case.  Below is my solution using an explicit stack

```
# ..., −8, 5, −3, 2, −1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ...

def bi_fibonacci(num1, num2):

    n = -1
    a = 1
    b = 0

    stack = []

    while n >= num1:
        if n <= num2:
            stack.append(a)

        a, b = b - a, a

        n -= 1

    if stack:
        yield from reversed(stack)

    n = 0
    a = 0
    b = 1

    while n <= num2:
        if n >= num1:
            yield a

        a, b = b, a + b

        n += 1

sequence = bi_fibonacci(-10, -5)
print(*sequence, sep=', ')

sequence = bi_fibonacci(-10, 10)
print(*sequence, sep=', ')

sequence = bi_fibonacci(5, 10)
print(*sequence, sep=', ')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
-55, 34, -21, 13, -8, 5
-55, 34, -21, 13, -8, 5, -3, 2, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55
5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55
>
```

Comment: In this solution, as we have created a LIST (stack) and appending the item, will it reduce performance when the numbers increases ? is it possible to use generators ?

Comment: @mAc, it costs a bit in *space* performance but if you consume all the numbers you request, it shouldn't cost anything in *speed* performance.  Only if you request a large range of negative numbers and then only consume a few would speed be an issue.  What kind of performance are you concerned with?